# How to await for a promise with an inner promise to be resolved?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise

I have an express app and want to return response only after the file is downloaded and decompressed. My code looks like this:

```
function downloadObject() {
  return getObject(...).then((archive) => {
    console.log("Downloaded.");
    fs.writeFileSync(...);
    return decompress(..., function(err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Decompression error.");
      } else {
        console.log("Decompressed");
      }
    });
  })
}

app.post("/download", async function (req, res) {
  await downloadObject();
  res.send('ready');
});
```

It does wait until the file is downloaded, however, it returns response before the file is decompressed. How can I make it wait for the inner promise to be resolved too?

Comment: What does `decompress` look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are actually returning the result of the `decompress` function, but it's an async function, so the return value doesn't really matter and is probably `undefined`.

What matters is the callback that you pass in, whose signature probably looks like the following :

```
decompress(..., function(err, result) {
   // Do what you want with the error and the result
})
```

To use promise instead of callback to achieve your asynchronous task, you can wrap your function in a promise like the following, and since your inside  the `then` of another Promise, it will *chain*.

```
function downloadObject() {
  return getObject(...).then((archive) => {
    console.log("Downloaded.");
    fs.writeFileSync(...);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
      decompress(..., function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        } else {
          resolve(result);
        }
      })
    );
  })
}
```

That's not all, it works, but we can do better. `writeFileSync` will block your `IO` in Node and we don't want that. Instead, it is preferable to use `writeFile` and everything would be cleaner using Promise chaining :

```
function downloadObject() {
  return getObject(...)
    .then((archive) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       fs.writeFile("<filename>", archive?.data, '<file-encoding>', err => {
         if (err) {
           reject(err);
         } else {
           resolve(archive);
         }
       })
    }))
    .then((archive) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      decompress(archive, function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        } else {
          resolve(result);
        }
      })
    }));
}
```

Of course, it's pseudo-code, I don't know what is in your `archive` object, nor do I know the type signature of your `decompress` function, but the point is to show how to wrap callback-style function in Promises, chain them and also handle errors properly with the `reject` function provided by the Promises.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing too much about `decompress`, I did notice it takes a callback.
That means it is itself an asynchronous function and immediately returns.

Use `util.promisify` to turn it into a regular promise-producing function:

```
async function downloadObject() {
  const archive = await getObject(...);
  console.log("Downloaded.");
  fs.writeFileSync(...); // Or `util.promisify(fs.writeFile)`
  try {
    await util.promisify(decompress)(...);
    console.log("Decompressed");
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Decompression error.");
  }
}
```

This function implements a common pattern that was mentioned in a now-deleted answer:

```
util.promisify = function (f) {
    return function(...args) {
       return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          f(...args, (err, result) => { err ? reject(err) : resolve(result); });
       })
    }
}
```